# How to change English format date to Spanish in bootstrap calendar?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, calendar

I have a bootstrap calendar and this shows days and months in English format.

I tried changing names for translation:

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
     monthNames: ['Enero','Febrero','Marzo','Abril','Mayo','Junio','Julio','Agosto','Septiembre','Octubre','Noviembre','Diciembre'],
    monthNamesShort: ['Ene','Feb','Mar','Abr','May','Jun','Jul','Ago','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dic'],
 dayNames: ['Domingo','Lunes', 'Martes','Miércoles','Jueves', 'Viernes','Sábado'],
 dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Lun', 'Mar','Mier','Jue', 'Vie','Sab'],
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    editable: true
});
});
```

But I want show Monday the first day of week not Sunday.

I tried adding:

```
 lang: 'es'
```

and

```
 language: 'es'
```

does not show the calendar....

How can I change this format?

Thanks!

Comment: did you check the [docs](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/)  of the plugin ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include this with your with scripts for Spanish: `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.4.0/lang/es.js`

```js
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
   header: {
     left: 'prev,next today',
     center: 'title',
     right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
   },
   defaultDate: '2015-09-1',
   editable: true,
   eventLimit: true // allow "more" link when too many events
 });
```

```css
body {
  margin: 40px 1px;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}
#calendar {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.4.0/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.4.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.4.0/lang/es.js"></script>
<div id='calendar'></div>
```